# Why does my text not orientate to the left?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my text in to be shifted to the left, but justify, side nor anchor do this.  I am using tkinter and python 3.

```
queue_frame = tk.Frame(master_frame)
queue_frame.pack()

queue_hash = tk.Label(queue_frame, text='#', width=3, font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'))
queue_hash.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

queue_name = tk.Label(queue_frame, text='Name', width=15, justify=tk.LEFT, font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'))
queue_name.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

queue_question_asked = tk.Label(queue_frame, text='Question Asked', width=25, font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'), justify=tk.LEFT)
queue_question_asked.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

queue_time = tk.Label(queue_frame, text='Time', width=15, font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'), justify=tk.LEFT)
queue_time.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference to Label options http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

Use anchor with the option 'w' and if you add relief = raised you can see the relative location of the text within the label.

```
import tkinter as tk
master_frame = tk.Tk()
queue_frame = tk.Frame(master_frame)
queue_frame.pack()
queue_hash = tk.Label(queue_frame,
                      text='#',
                      width=3,
                      relief='raised')
queue_hash.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
queue_name = tk.Label(queue_frame,
                      text='Name',
                      width=15,
                      anchor='w',
                      relief='raised')
queue_name.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
queue_question_asked = tk.Label(queue_frame,
                                text='Question Asked',
                                width=25,
                                relief='raised',
                                anchor='w')
queue_question_asked.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
queue_time = tk.Label(queue_frame,
                      text='Time',
                      width=15,
                      relief='raised',
                      anchor='w')
queue_time.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
master_frame.mainloop()
```